# Xamarin Forms proceso muy lento

Tags: c#, hilos, xamarin.forms

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente problema, cuando llamo esta funcion mi vista se vuelve super lenta y me manda a esperar o cerrar alguien sabe a que se deba??

```
    private MediaFile _image;
    // este mediafile lo asigno con un evento de la camara 
       private async void btnCamara_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera soportada.", "OK");
            return;
        }
        _image = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Directory = "auto_" + idx,
            Name = "auto.jpg"
        });
        if (_image == null)
            return;
         var xlocal = _image.Path;

        imgx.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => {
            return _image.GetStream();  });

        //_image.Path
      _ = b64img();


    }

    //
    private async Task b64img() {
        try
        {

            byte[] b =  System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_image.Path);
            String s = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
            b64.Text = s;

            colorx.IsVisible = false;
            btnCamara.IsVisible = false;
            btnGal.IsVisible = false;



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

           await DisplayAlert("error", ex.ToString(), "ok");
        }
    }
```

la llamo cuando termino otro metodo con un `_ = b64img();`

Comment: Podes poner el codigo completo? de donde lo llamas

Comment: Seguramente se debe a que no estas usando la tarea y eso bloquea el hilo principal de la app, entonces cuando tocas la pantalla intenta hacer algo, no puede y te avisa que esta bloqueada, si cerras o esperas.

Comment: ¿Me explicas ese `_ = b64img()` por favor?

Comment: @fredyfx es para llamar a mi Task

Answer (score 0):

El porqué es lento puede depender de muchos factores. Lo que si está claro es que estas llamando a tu Task b64img() y en el método en el que lo estás llamado no lo estás esperando. Esto hace que tu hilo principal se bloquee como bien a comentado Ramiro Barone.

```
await b64img();
```